# How to create a twig that lets you choose a color(colorpicker)?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I tried to create a color picker for my HTML form in symfony and it works perfectly fine. I also tried using a twig for my form but then i dont seem to make it as i expected.
I tried using the GenemuFormBundle:https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/color/index.md  but its not working for me, maybe i just missed something there but is there any other way to create a twig form for my colorpicker and fetch the *Hex Value* of the color chosen and set the value to my entity?. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of including a Bundle for a simple color picker you should include this cdn link [bootstrap-colorpicker](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js)

only in the places you require a color picker. In the formtype add a textfield for the color picker. Then in the twig template page do the following:

```
$('#form_text_field').colorpicker();
```

For more customized colorpicker refer to [this doc](https://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/)

This is simpler and cleaner.